# Global userDefineLang.xml for notepad++

Tags: xml, notepad++, config, highlighting

Notepad++ will automatically grab all user defined languages defined within userDefineLang.xml.  No importing is involved. This file must be located within directory (C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++).

Alternatively, you can import a language by opening notepad++ and doing 'Language | Define Your Language ... | Import'. Then when you reopen notepad++, the user defined language will be available

QUESTION: I want the automatic import language feature which you get when using the userDefineLang.xml ... However, I want this userDefineLang.xml to be opened by notepad++ no matter who the user (regardless of who logs onto the computer).  Currently, userDefineLang.xml is user-specific.  My goal is for the language to be available to all users who log onto the Computer. Is this possible with notepad++?

Answer (score 2):

Are you using a Windows OS? You can create a batch (.bat extension) script that copy the userDefineLang.xml at startup and put it into "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup".

You can use something like

```
xcopy C:\userDefileLang.xml %AppData%\Notepad++\ /d /y
```

- **/d:** copy only if the origin file it's different from the destination file.
- **/y:** overwrite the destination file.

Obviously you can change the origin file, I've made an example with userDefineLang.xml into C:\

Let me know if you need assistence for the .bat file.

Note: I assumed that you have to copy the userDefinelang.xml into one computer without a ActiveDirectory domain, otherwise there is a little differenced method that deploy the script into all computers of your organization.

More information on xcopy command: [Microsoft Support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/240268)

Comment: Yes, this is true and a good point.  Could have put placed a shortcut to the *.bat file inside the 'Start Menu|Programs|Startup' direcotry.  Was trying to minimize mods to the computer, but this solution is a good workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple things that I had to do that fixed the problem:

1. The `AppData` Folder is hidden. Un-hide it. (This tip is not for pros)
2. Paste the `userdefinelang.xml` in the notepad++ folder and make sure to add `<NotepadPlus>` opening and closing tags
3. The `go.xml` file in the Program Files(x86)/Notepad++ folder must have additional XML header `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252" ?>`
4. The `go` language option appears at the bottom in the Lang Menu.

Answer (score 0):

Update: the feature described above is not currently available in Notepad++; was just never requested before.  This was discovered after posting to their sourceForge page.  Got a reply to my question and solution was to create a ticket for capability.  So all good.

https://sourceforge.net/p/notepad-plus/feature-requests/2605/